# Python - Returning a traversed matrix using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, traversal

Let's say i have a matrix like this:

```
array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]
```

I want to make a method that basically loops through the matrix and print out the integers like so:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

But I want to do this recursively so I can get more experience with it. I currently have this method with a helper:

```
def flatten_array(matrix):
 return str(helper(len(matrix), len(matrix[0]), 0, 0, matrix))


def helper(current_row, current_col, i, j, matrix):
    s = ''
    if i >= current_row:
        return 1
    elif j >= current_col:
        return helper(current_row, current_col, i + 1, 0, matrix)
    else:
        s += str(matrix[i][j]) + ','
        print(matrix[i][j], end=',')
        helper(current_row, current_col, i, j + 1, matrix)
        return s
```

it prints this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
```

But i actually want to return this rather than printing, can anyone help with this?

Comment: I know that you want to loop through the matrix, but you can o ```x=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(array))```. This will return a flat list

Comment: If you want to ```return``` the values and not ```print```, you have to store them in a ```list``` inside your function and ```return``` them at the end.

Comment: You could return a list, then do `",".join(xxx)`

Comment: @Sujay I rather stick to solving this purely recursively without any libraries or other inbuilt methods

Comment: Check this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-flatten-a-nested-list-using-recursion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code to `return` the flattened list instead of printing. I have passed an additional parameter `ans` which is a `list` to store the values of matrix.

```
array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

def flatten_array(matrix):
 return helper(len(matrix), len(matrix[0]), 0, 0, matrix, [])


def helper(current_row, current_col, i, j, matrix, ans):
    if i >= current_row:
        return 1
    elif j >= current_col:
        return helper(current_row, current_col, i + 1, 0, matrix, ans)
    else:
        ans.append(matrix[i][j])
        helper(current_row, current_col, i, j + 1, matrix, ans)
        return ans

print(flatten_array(array))
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost-certainly want [`itertools.chain.from_iterable(array)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) for this

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> array = [
...     [1, 2, 3],
...     [4, 5, 6],
...     [7, 8, 9]
... ]
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(array))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

NOTE that if you were just going to iterate over the flattened list, you can directly do so and avoid creating an intermediate list, as `.from_iterable()` returns an iterable

Comment: *I rather stick to solving this purely recursively without any libraries or other inbuilt methods* was clearly mentioned by OP in the comments